# Bayesian Linear Regression Example in the Deeplearning Book

Tags: regression, bayesian, linear

I'm reading the deeplearning book authored by Ian Goodfellow about the Bayesian linear regression in [Section 5.6](http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/ml.html).

I have two questions. Please advise me. Thanks!

**Question 1.** Why $p({\boldsymbol {w| X, y}}) \propto p({\boldsymbol { y|X,w}})p({\boldsymbol w})$ as in equation (5.74)?

I tried to derive the proportional relationship as such.
\begin{align}
p({\boldsymbol {w|X,y}}) = \frac{p({\boldsymbol {w, X, y}})}{p({\boldsymbol {X,y}})} = \frac{p({\boldsymbol {y|X,w}})p({\boldsymbol {X,w}})}{p({\boldsymbol {X,y}})} = \frac{p({\boldsymbol {y|X,w}})p({\boldsymbol {X|w}})p(\boldsymbol w)}{p({\boldsymbol{X,y}})} 
\end{align}
That $p({\boldsymbol {w| X, y}}) \propto p({\boldsymbol { y|X,w}})p({\boldsymbol w})$ implies that $\frac{p({\boldsymbol {X|w}})}{p({\boldsymbol {X,y}})}$ is a constant (correct me if I'm wrong). But why whould $\frac{p({\boldsymbol {X|w}})}{p({\boldsymbol {X,y}})}$ be a constant? I could not figure it out.

**Question 2.** Looking at equation (5.76), how on earth does one come up with the definition of $\boldsymbol \Lambda_m$ and $\boldsymbol \mu_m$ and rewriting equation (5.76) into (5.77)? The substitution does not look intuitive nor straightforward to me. I tried to derive equation (5.77) from (5.76) by myself, as follows.
\begin{align}
{\boldsymbol {
-2y^{\top}Xw + w^{\top}X^{\top}Xw + w^{\top}\Lambda_{0}^{-1}w - 2\mu_{0}^{\top}\Lambda_{0}^{-1}w
}}
={\boldsymbol {
w^{\top}(X^{\top}X + \Lambda_{0}^{-1})w - 2(y^{\top}X + \mu_{0}^{\top}\Lambda_{0}^{-1})w
}}
\end{align}

I am kind of stuck here. How to go any further? The 
$({\boldsymbol {X^{\top}X + \Lambda_{0}^{-1}
}})$
looks like
$\boldsymbol \Lambda_m$
but not exactly 
$\boldsymbol \Lambda_m$.
It is the inverse of
$\boldsymbol \Lambda_m$. And how about $\boldsymbol \mu_m$? Where on earth does it come from?

Below gives the excerpt of the chapter from the book.

[image: Bayesian Linear Regression]

Answer (score 1):

For question 1, to explicitly show how it follows from Bayes rule, we'd write 
$$p(w|y,x)=\frac{p(y|w,x)p(w|x)}{p(y|x)},$$
but we can just assume $w$ and $x$ are independent and write 
$$p(w|y,x)\propto p(y|w,x)p(w)$$

As for question 2, this is just a standard computation of the posterior of a normal-normal model, see (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_linear_regression) for the same problem worked out in some more detail with a slightly different prior or (https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Papers/bayesGauss.pdf) for the non-regression case.